# submeter um formulário com jQuery clicando em um botão fora do formulário

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de enviar um `form` sem clicar no botão `submit`, utilizando o evento click do jQuery, tentei dessa forma mas não obtive êxito:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var form = $("#form_" + id);
    
    form.submit(function() {
      alert('pronto!');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id='form_7' action="" method='POST'>
    <input type='text'>
  </form>
</div>

<button class='item' rel='7'>Botão</button>
```

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dois problemas:

- retira o `#` do atributo ID no HTML. Deve ser somente `id="form_7"` e não `id='#form_7'`
- o método submit não aceita argumentos, deve ser somente `form.submit();`

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1z2wc5j5/

Comment: Sergio, boa tarde. Eu gostaria de enviar os dados usando o ajax, eu consigo fazer isso clicando no submit, assim: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gciuolhaxt60je3/exemplo.js?dl=0

Agora se eu criar um evento como informei não consigo

Comment: @TalesBreno porque não fazes assim: https://jsfiddle.net/1z2wc5j5/1/ ?

Comment: a sua ultima sugestão deu certo, só precisei fazer uma adaptação no meu arquivo ajax(que não implica no sucesso da sua sugestão), que era onde estava o erro. Muito obrigado! :D

Comment: @TalesBreno ótimo! Fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Criei algo mais genérico que funciona tipo o `for` do `label`

Para usar basta criar

- `button[type="submit"]` ou `input[type="submit"]` ou `.submit`
- Adicionar um atributo `for` com o id do formulário que quer enviar.

```js
// Alerta para mostrar que o form foi enviado
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).find('input[name="value"]').val());
});

// Evento de envio de form
// Funciona com 'button[type="submit"]', 'input[type="submit"]', '.submit'
$('body').on('click', 'button[type="submit"], input[type="submit"], .submit', function(){
  var id = this.getAttribute('for');
  var form = $('form[id="'+id+'"]');
  if(form.size()>0){
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
.submit{
  border: solid 1px #084884;
  border-radius:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="teste1">
  <input name="value" type="text" value="1"/>
</form>

<form id="teste2">
  <input name="value" type="text" value="2"/>
</form>

<form id="teste3">
  <input name="value" type="text" value="3"/>
</form>

<ul>
   <li><input type="submit" for="teste1" value="Enviar Form 1"/></li>
  <li><input type="submit" for="teste2" value="Enviar Form 2"/></li>
  <li><input type="submit" for="teste3" value="Enviar Form 3"/></li>
</ul>

<span class="submit" for="teste2">Enviar Form 2</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso via Javascript...

Primeiramente crie uma função javascript que vai pegar seu form pelo ID e submeter.
ex:

```
function submete() {
document.getElementById('IDDOSEUFORM').submit();
}
```

E após isso, adicione uma ação no clique no seu botão, a função onclick chamando o método do javascript.
ex:

```
<button class='item' rel='7' onclick="submete();">Botão</button>
```